# Vimeo authentication OAuth2

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, oauth, vimeo

I am trying to authenticate with Vimeo via iOS app. I am using `GTMOAuth2Authentication` Oauth2 library. My code is as follows:

```
- (void)signInToVimeo
{
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth = [self authForVimeo];

    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * viewController = 
    [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:auth

    authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]

    keychainItemName:@"VimeoKeychainItem"
                                                                                 delegate:self

    finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:

    finishedWithAuth:error:)];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}

- (GTMOAuth2Authentication * )authForVimeo
{
    NSURL * tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:VIMEO_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL];

    NSString * redirectURI = @"vimeoTest://";

    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth;

    auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication   

    authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"Vimeo"

    tokenURL:tokenURL

    redirectURI:redirectURI

    clientID:CLIENT_ID                                   

    clientSecret:SECRET_KEY];
    auth.scope = @"edit";
    return auth;
}

- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * )viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication * )auth
                 error:(NSError * )error
{
    NSLog(@"auth access token: %@", auth.accessToken);
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

I have the same callback URL `vimeoTest://` set in URL schemes in app as well as Vimeo developer site. The Vimeo login screen displays well, and after entering login credentials asks for "allow" or "cancel"; that's fine but when I tap "Allow", I am not getting device token with error message "com.google.HTTPStatus error 404." Is there any example for Vimeo authentication and uploading?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error when i've changed the callback URL to my own. This is because the callback URL MUST be in form vimeoCLIENT_ID if You are using VIMNetworking. Why? If You check VIMNetworking sources You'll noticed that

```
- (id<VIMRequestToken>)authenticateWithCodeGrantResponseURL:(NSURL *)responseURL completionBlock:(VIMAccountCompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

uses

```
- (NSString *)codeGrantRedirectURI
{
   NSString *authRedirectScheme = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"vimeo%@", self.clientKey];
   NSString *authRedirectPath = @"auth";
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@", authRedirectScheme, authRedirectPath];
}
```

look at the authRedirectScheme string ;)